# monotone convergence in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need help with this analysis problem.

Deﬁne a sequence ${t_n}$ recursively by setting $t_1 = 1$ and $t_n = \sqrt{(t_{n-1} + 1)}$. Does this sequence converge? To what?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $t_n>0$ for all $n$ and let $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_{n}=L$, then you have that
$t_n=\sqrt{t_{n-1}+1}\implies t_n^2=t_{n-1}+1\implies \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_{n-1}+1\implies L^2=L+1\implies L=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$

Answer (score 0):

One way to show convergence is to show that the sequence is monotonically increasing and bounded above.

I'll show monotonicity by induction. The inductive hypothesis is that $t_n>t_{n-1} \forall n$.

From the recurrence relation, $t_2=\sqrt{t_1+1} = \sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt2$. So it is clear that $t_2-t_1>0$, establishing the base case.

Now assume $t_k>t_{k-1}$ for some $k$. It needs to be now shown that $t_{k+1}>t_k$.

Consider $t_{k+1}^2-t_k^2 = (t_{k}+1)-(t_{k-1}+1)>0$ by the recurrence relation and inductive hypothesis. Hence,
$$\begin{align} t_{k+1}^2-t_k^2&>0\\(t_{k+1}-t_k)(t_{k+1}+t_k)&>0 
\\
t_{k+1}-t_k &> 0
\end{align}$$

The last step follows since $t_{k+1}+t_k>0$.

In a similar way you can show that the sequence is bounded above by a constant, such as $2$. This then guarantees convergence and the existence of a limit, and you can then use Integral's answer to get the limit $L$ as $\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$.